# open 1 content at a time

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I want to toggle between the two tabs with following conditions:

1. If I click on Tab 1, tab1 content should open (if tab2 content is
   open, it should close or remain closed(collapsed) if it is already
   closed(collapsed)) and vice-versa for Tab 2
2. If Tab 1 is already open and I click on Tab 1 again, it should remain open and Tab 2 should remain close (collapsed).

```html
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="panel-group">
    <h4><a class="accordion-toggle number1-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">Tab1 <small>[+]</small></a></h4>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="number1 accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h4><a class="accordion-toggle number2-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo">Tab2 <small>[+]</small></a></h4>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="number2 accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Seeing as you are using bootstrap take a look at this tutorial on how to accomplish this: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tabs_pills.asp

Answer (score 2):

Based on the link i provided i create this for you:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Tab1 <small>[+]</small></a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Tab2 <small>[+]</small></a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content col-md-2">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>Tab 1</h3>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Tab 2</h3>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```